# commercetools: How to use getDiscountedPricePerQuantity()?

Tags: java, commercetools

In the commercetools JVM SDK we were using the, now deprecated method, `LineItem#getDiscountedPrice()`, but now the `LineItem#getDiscountedPricePerQuantity()` method is written in the [Javadoc](http://sphereio.github.io/sphere-jvm-sdk/javadoc/master/io/sphere/sdk/carts/LineItemLike.html#getDiscountedPrice--) that it should be used instead. It, however, returns a list of `DiscountedLineItemPriceForQuantity` for each `LineItem`. What does this list represent? Shouldn't it always have one discount for the line item? Is this documented how to use somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a discount from 10 €.

If you want to apply this discount to a cart with 2 items, then each item is discounted from 5 €. That is the simple case. And in that case, the list contains one element with a quantity of 2.

But if the cart has 3 items, then the discount cannot be applied equally to all items. 2 items should receive a discount of 3,33 € and one item should receive a discount of 3,34 € so that the total is 10 €. In that case, the list should contain 2 elements:

- one element with a quantity of 2 with a discount of 3,33 €
- one element with a quantity of 1 with a discount of 3,34 €